# ¿Cómo crear objetos DOM y recorrerlos con un for of en JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Tengo el siguiente bucle recorriendo unos datos, pero ¿Cómo puedo transformarla en objetos DOM y recorrerla correctamente? Gracias!

```
resultado.innerHTML = '';

for (let item of datos) {
    // console.log(item.name);
    resultado.innerHTML += `
        <tr>
            <td class="colorNombre">${item.name}</td>
            <td class="colorDireccion">${item.address.street}</td>
            <td class="colorCiudad">${item.address.city}</td>
        </tr>`
}
```

Comment: ¿Lo que pretendes es crear un `tr` por cada elemento del *array* `datos`?

Comment: si correcto y luego recorrerlo de alguna manera

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Realmente lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
for(let item of datos) {
   var tr = document.createElement('tr');

   var elementos = [item.name, item.address.street, item.address.city];
   var clases = ['colorNombre', 'colorDireccion', 'colorCiudad'];

   for(var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');

      td.setAttribute('class', clases[i]);
      td.innerText = elementos[i];

      tr.appendChild(td);
   }

   resultado.appendChild(tr);
}
```

Así añadiras los objetos usando DOM y un una string.

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta @z3nth10n era lo que estaba buscando un saludo !

Comment: Es una mala práctica modificar constantemente el DOM dentro de bucles. Es mejor crear todo en una cadena y **hacer append una sola vez**, o mejor aún crear un fragmento del DOM ([ver aquí](https://howchoo.com/code/learn-the-slow-and-fast-way-to-append-elements-to-the-dom)) Así el código queda optimizado.

Comment: @A.Cedano interesante, podrias crear una respuesta indicando lo que dices? Me gustaria a mi y creo que a los demas miembros de la comunidad, ver ese detalle

Answer (score 8):

Referente al detalle que comentaba @A.Cedano

Crear un elemento y añadirlo al elemento padre por cada iteración va a suponer que el DOM tiene que renderizar `n` veces el elemento padre, donde `n` es la longitud del *array*.

Por ello, una solución más óptima es crear un *array* de todos esos elementos que queremos añadir y, una vez los tengamos todos, añadirlos de una sola vez.

Podemos usar [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) para crear un elemento `tr` por cada elemento de `datos`.

```
const rows = datos.map(createTableRow);
resultado.append(...rows);
```

La función `createTableRow` tendrá un *item* del *array* por parámetro y retornará un elemento `tr`.

```
const createTableRow = ({ name, address }) => {
    const createColumn = (value, klass) => {
        const column = document.createElement('td');
        column.innerHTML = value;
        column.className = klass;
        return column;
    }

    const row = document.createElement('tr');

    row.append(
        createColumn(name, 'colorNombre'),
        createColumn(address.street, 'colorDireccion'),
        createColumn(address.city, 'colorCiudad')
    );
    
    return row;
}
```

Dejo [la documentación de `Node.append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) por si fuera necesario.

También dejo [un *fiddle*](https://jsfiddle.net/VRoxa/Lc7hus1f/3) con un pequeño ejemplo del código.

> **Disclaimer**
> La respuesta de @z3nth10n es totalmente válida.
> Sólo quería proponer otra forma de hacerlo.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, me parece genial que la sugerencia sea trabajar sobre elementos HTML en lugar de una cadena y agregar todo solo con `apend()`. En lugar de `fiddle`, podrías agregar el ejemplo directamente en la respuesta con un [fragmento de código ejecutable](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1450/54039)

Comment: Hola, @Triby, gracias por el comentario. La verdad es que prefiero el fiddle. Si agrego todo el fragmento de código ejecutable en el mismo post, puede ofuscar la respuesta. Prefiero dejar las cosas triviales como el HTML o el CSS (o la declaración del array de datos) en un fiddle para centrar la atención en lo que realmente importa.

Comment: Sería más fácil para ti crear todo aquí mismo y, para evitar esas distracciones, el fragmento de código se puede colocar oculto, de forma que aparezca un enlace para mostrar y ejecutar. Por supuesto, solo estoy sugiriendo una opción que es cuestión de preferencias y, en verdad, no afecta cuando hay una buena respuesta, bien detallada y documentada, como en este caso.

Answer (score 5):

Si te interesa escribir **código optimizado**, podrías hacerlo también mediante el uso de `DocumentFragment`. Al final de la respuesta pongo algunas cosas sobre esta propiedad del DOM, porque me parece que es una gran desconocida, siendo que debería ser la herramienta ideal para añadir contenido masivo en el DOM.

Por ejemplo:

```js
/*Set de datos de ejemplo*/
var datos = [
  {
    name: "Pedro",
    address: {street:"1st Street", city:"New York"}
  },
  {
    name: "Marta",
    address: {street:"2nd Street", city:"París"}
  },  
  {
    name: "Juan",
    address: {street:"3th Street", city:"London"}
  } 
  ]
  
var resultado  = document.getElementById('oneTable'); 
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

/*OJO: Esto se definía N veces en el bucle*/
var clases = ['colorNombre', 'colorDireccion', 'colorCiudad'];
  
for(let item of datos) {
   var tr = document.createElement('tr');
   var tds = [item.name, item.address.street, item.address.city];

   for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; ++i) {
      var td = document.createElement('td');
      td.setAttribute('class', clases[i]);
      /*createTextNode es más seguro para agregar contenido*/
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(tds[i]));      
      tr.appendChild(td);
      fragment.appendChild(tr);
   }
}
/*
  Agregamos el fragmento al elemento del DOM
  al salir del bucle, de modo que el DOM
  se renderizará una sola vez, no N veces
*/
resultado.appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bulma@0.9.1/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table is-bordered is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth" id="oneTable">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Street</th>
    <th>City</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

### Un gran desconocido

En la web, incluyendo nuestro querido Stackoverflow.es, cada vez que se trata de crear elementos del DOM en bucles, lo que se suele ver es código basado en una práctica no recomendada que consistiría en hacer append de esos elementos directamente en el DOM dentro del bucle.

Quienes programan con tal ingenuidad ignoran que la modificación del DOM tiene una precio. Cada vez que haces `append` dentro de un bucle significa que el DOM se va a renderizar `N` veces. Por tanto, si el bucle tiene mil elementos, habrá mil renderizaciones del DOM. Hay prácticas peores, que hacen varios `append` dentro de un mismo bucle, multiplicando las `N` renderizaciones por esa cantidad de `append`.

Hay un gran olvidado para estos casos, se llama `createDocumentFragment()`, el cual, según MDN:

> Crea un nuevo [DocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) vacio, dentro del cual un nodo del
> DOM puede ser adicionado para construir un nuevo arbol DOM fuera de
> pantalla.
>
> DocumentFragment son Nodos del DOM que nunca forman parte del arbol
> DOM. El caso de uso más común es crear un document fragment, agregar
> elementos al document fragment y luego agregar dicho document fragment
> al arbol del DOM. En el arbol del DOM, el document fragment es
> remplazado por todos sus hijos.
>
> Dado que el document fragment es generado en memoria y no como parte
> del arbol del DOM, agregar elementos al mismo no causan [reflow](http://code.google.com/speed/articles/reflow.html)
> (computo de la posicion y geometria de los elementos) en la pagina.
> Como consecuencia, usar document fragments usualmente resultan en
> [mejor performance](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/).

---

### PD

He introducido algunas mejoras en el código, sin detenerme a analizar la forma de leer los datos en el objeto. En ese sentido la respuesta de @VRoxa parece ser más simple.

La intención de mi respuesta es mostrar un ejemplo de uso de `DocumentFragment`, según la petición de [@JuanRivera en su comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/431281/c%C3%B3mo-crear-objetos-dom-y-recorrerlos-con-un-for-of-en-javascript/431282?noredirect=1#comment770047_431282).

Comment: Cada día se aprende algo nuevo, ese `gran desconocido` me será muy útil y seguramente lo voy a comenzar a aplicar en mis proyectos y ejercicios.